# iOS 4.3.5 and infinite loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

iOS 4.3.5 and infinite loop

Sombody got this strange bug ?

1) Create some app and add this code lines at anywhere

```
..
NSLog(@"app is started");
..
while (true)
{
// do nothing
}
```

2) Run this app in iPhone iOS 4.3.5 and get infinite loop

3) Press Home, then double click on Home, and Tap on '-' for kill a app

4) Tap on app for relaunch him after 1 sec, 3 sec, 10 sec, 60 sec or 900 sec.

5) App is not closing, is not crashing, it is running continuously. It can never be closed

What's wrong ? This is iOS 4.3.5 problem?

And, can i know, what user is trying close a app?

It seems SIGKILL is not getting called

Thanks

Comment: soon it will be released the ios6.0, why bother with 4.3?

Comment: There are devices out there which cannot even upgrade to 4.3.

Comment: You are trying on an iPhone device, and not the iPhone Simulator, right?

Comment: I have me too a project on which we must support iphone3 ( not 3G) and  that has ios 4.2 maximum. The question is, will those customers buy your app, who aren't whiling to get an iphone 4 ( when iphone5 is launched already) ? If not, than why make back compatibility to era? I had to many issues supporting under 5.0 and backward compatibility and ofc will not pay those my app, who still has iphone3. iPad1 has ios 5.1 ...

Comment: @matheszabi iOS developer is bother for all iOS versions after iOS 3.2

Comment: @Devraj this is just a example, but iOS must kill any app with any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in iOS 4. In iOS 5 and older it is working fine.

Answer (score -2):

**while(true)** is equal to **while(1)** which will lead to infinite loop in any computer programming language, if you don't give any condition to break the loop. Its not an iOS 4.3.5 issue.

[Refer this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)

Comment: Yeah that's pretty obvious, but the OP wants to know why SIGKILL isn't killing the process, like it would in any other POSIX environment.

Comment: Try do this code at another iOS version. SIGKILL will kill app at truely, but not in iOS 4.3.5